# angularJS ng-repeat filter not working with dynamic field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I have a code as follow:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filteredText">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {Name : filteredText}">

    </li>
</ul>
```

When *Name* property is static it's work correctly. Now I need filter dynamic field. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {propertyName: filteredText}">

    </li>
</ul>
```

In this case *propertyName* is dynamic and come from `$scope`. But this case `filter` not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), it looks like you have to do it another way.

```
<input ng-show="propertyFilter == 'Name'" 
       type="text"
       ng-model="filteredText[propertyName]" />

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: filteredText">

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But I don't know count of **propertyName**, propertyName come from controller dynamically and I must put it filter syntax

Comment: @vaqifrv that way it's quite easier. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4k6kmLd/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="line in lines | filter:custom()">
      <p>
      {{line.Name}}
      </p>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.filteredText = 'tiago';
    $scope.propertyName = 'Name'

    $scope.custom = function(){
      var object = {};
      object[$scope.propertyName] = $scope.filteredText;

        return object;
    }

    $scope.lines = [
        {Name: '23', age: 20},
      {Name: 'tiago', age: 23}
    ];
}
```